# Create an HTML element with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I would like some pointers on how to rewrite the post to have links to hashtags. I need to have `link_to( ..........)` inside the post after I rewrite it and I can't really figure out how to do that in the backend application.

The current method I am trying to use is:

```
 def twitify(tweet = '')
    tweet.gsub!(/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/) do |tag|
      link_to("##{tag}", '#')
    end
  end
```

However this only gives me:

```
jdawiodwiajdaw<a href="/"> #mergiCaTeCrap</a>  (which is not a link)
```

This is the HTML:

```
<li id="tweet-<%= tweet.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(tweet.user, size: 50), tweet.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to tweet.user.name, tweet.user %></span>
  <span class="content">
  <%= twitify(tweet.content) %>
      <%= image_tag tweet.picture.url if tweet.picture? %>
</span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(tweet.created_at) %> ago.
    <% if current_user?(tweet.user) %>
      <%= link_to "delete", tweet, method: :delete,
                                       data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
    <% end %>
  </span>
</li>
```

I would like it to not show me the href thing, how would I do that?

Comment: `link_to` has many different implementations I would suggest looking at `link_to(url,html_options ={}) do ...` so something like `link_to('#') { tweet.gsub!(/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/,'') }` although I have not bothered to evaluate your expression as it is fairly complex.

Comment: i found the expression on a website it works well, i just needed how to make an actual link there i will test it shortly :D as i closed my laptop

Comment: it does make me a link it's ok , however it does a link for the whole post, i must see how I cann add a link for every tag element as i have in my twitify method, thank you very much i shall now try to do it for every hashtag

Comment: it seems that I can't manage to do multiple links to if let's say I have more than 1 hashtag in that post... is it doable with link_to ? i kinda get that <a href="#">...</a> thingy

Comment: I answered but just to keep the comments from going on forever because your code is already correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because Rails is escaping the html tags due to security reasons, in this case you just have to call the `html_safe` on the `link_to` like so:

```
def twitify(tweet = '')
 tweet.gsub(/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/) do |tag|
  " " + link_to("#{tag.strip}", '#')
 end.html_safe
end
```

You should be good to go!

Comment: you are perfectly right . Sorry I answered so late . I randomly saw html_safe yesterday while I was searching the answer before i really had to leave. Wanted to try it today . I was very happy to see that this indeed would solve the problem :D !

Answer (score 1):

Okay first of all there is nothing wrong with the way you are going about it.

```
def twitify(tweet = '')
  tweet.gsub(/(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!(?:\d+|\w+?_|_\w+?)(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/) do |tag|
    " " + link_to("#{tag.strip}", '#')
  end
end
```

All I did was avoid modifying the original tweet (used `gsub` instead of the bang method `gsub!`), added a space before the `#hash_tag`,removed the extra `#` and space from the link.

As you can see

```
 tweet = "This is a #tweet and it can make #hash_tags into #links"
 twitify(tweet)
 #=> "This is a <a href=\"#\">#tweet</a> and it can make <a href=\"#\">#hash_tags</a> into <a href=\"#\">#links</a>"
 #your implementation 
 original_twitify(tweet)
 #=> "This is a <a href=\"#\"># #tweet</a> and it can make <a href=\"#\"># #hash_tags</a> into <a href=\"#\"># #links</a>"
```

So I don't think there is really an issue here you pretty much had everything correct.

Comment: this works fine , as does mine the problem indeed was as kurenn said. Thank you very much for your answer!